# Ruby/Rails: suppress superclass functions - integration of Stripe and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, stripe-payments

I have a create method in my RegistrationsController, which inherits from Devise::Registrations controller. It is supposed to call Stripe and if the creation of a customer is successful, it saves the user and sends a confirmation email, which is handled by '#create' in Devise. If the call to Stripe fails, it is supposed to set a flash and not save the user or send an email, i.e. suppress the Devise 'create' method. The method works fine if the call to Stripe is successful, but if it is not successful, the user is still saved and the confirmation email is still sent.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    super 
    @user = resource
    result = UserSignup.new(@user).sign_up(params[:stripeToken], params[:plan])

    if result.successful?
      return
    else
      flash[:error] = result.error_message
      # TODO: OVERIDE SUPER METHOD SO THE CONFIRM EMAIL IS 
      # NOT SENT AND USER IS NOT SAVED / EXIT THE METHOD
    end
  end
```

I have tried skip_confirmation!, this just bypasses the need for confirmation. resource.skip_confirmation_notification! also does not work. I have also tried redefining resource.send_confirmation_instructions; nil; end; My thought was to exit the create method altogether in the else block. How can I exit the create method or suppress 'super' in the else block, or would another approach be better? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling `super` at the top of your override, the whole registration process will take place, signing up your user, and only then executing your code.

You need to override [Devise's registrations_controller.rb create action](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L14) code by copy and pasting the whole and inserting your call like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    # Here you call Stripe
    result = UserSignup.new(@user).sign_up(params[:stripeToken], params[:plan]) 
    if result.successful?
      resource.save
    else
      flash[:error] = result.error_message
    end

    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
end
```

Notice that `resource.save` is only called if `result.successful?`.

Comment: This worked, thanks. I had to define "set minimum password length" in the private methods of the controller, I got it from DeviseController. I also changed the next line 'respond_with resource' to ,redirect_to new_user_registration_path(plan: params[:plan])' so that a failed sign up or credit card transaction directs the user to the same sign up page.

Comment: Great to know! You can edit my answer if you think it'll help others.